# GUI is not opening after Oracle solaris x86 installation

Tags: operating-system, solaris-10

I'm Installing oracle Solaris 86x64 operating system in my PC. it was complete installation without any errors. In the final step of the installation the GUI window is not opening. If I restart the PC it is booting and Not able to go beyond the black screen. But, I can ping the system from another Command prompt. Is there drivers to be install ?  Because of this I'm not able go into the system.

Comment: How should anyone know without a clue about your hardware ? Is the LiveCD showing a graphic desktop ? What Solaris release is this ?

Comment: @jlliagre Solaris 5.10, 3GB RAM and 500 GB HDR

Comment: Why not Solaris 11 ? The RAM and hard disk size aren't that much relevant when investigation a graphic issue. What is your graphic card ? Can you boot in single user mode ? Did you try a verbose boot ?